# My php script wont send proper emails

Tags: php, html

I created a php script for an online application that I have built online. The code seems to be able to send emails, but I the emails I receive do not contain any of the information that are filled into the online application. I am not sure what is wrong...

Help!

HTML

```
<html>
<p align="left"><form action="application.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="JobApp" lang="en">
<div align="left"><strong>Personal Details</strong></div>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" align="right" valign="top"><span id="sprytextfield1">
      <label for="fullname">Full Name:*</label>
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
    <td width="35%" align="left" valign="top"><input name="fullname" type="text" id="fullname" size="35" maxlength="100"></td>
    <td width="40%" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top"><span id="sprytextfield2">
      <label for="address">Street Address:*</label>
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="address" type="text" id="address" size="35"></td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top"><span id="sprytextfield3">
      <label for="city">City:*</label>
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="city" type="text" id="city" size="30"></td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top"><span id="spryselect1">
      <label for="province">Province:*</label>
      <span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select an item.</span></span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><select name="province" id="province">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
      <option value="Alberta">Alberta</option>
      <option value="British Columbia">British Columbia</option>
      <option value="Manitoba">Manitoba</option>
      <option value="New Burnswick">New Burnswick</option>
      <option value="Newfoundland and Labrador">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
      <option value="Nova Scotia">Nova Scotia</option>
      <option value="Ontario">Ontario</option>
      <option value="Others">Others</option>
      <option value="Prince Edward Island">Prince Edward Island</option>
      <option value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
      <option value="Saskatchewan">Saskatchewan</option>
    </select></td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top"><span id="sprytextfield4">
      <label for="postal">Postal Code:*</label>
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="postal" type="text" id="postal" size="15" maxlength="7"></td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top"><span id="sprytextfield5">
      <label for="email">Email Address:*</label>
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="35"></td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top"><span id="sprytextfield6">
      <label for="phone">Phone Number:*</label>
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="25"></td>
    <td align="left"><span id="spryradio1">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="phonetype" value="Cell Phone" id="phonetype_0">
        Cell Phone</label>
      <br>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="phonetype" value="Home Phone" id="phonetype_1">
        Home Phone</label>
      <br>
      <span class="radioRequiredMsg">Please make a selection.</span></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<p><div align="left"><strong> Relevant Experience</strong></div>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" align="right" valign="top"><span id="spryselect2">
      <label for="position">Position of Interest:*</label>
      <span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select an item.</span></span></td>
    <td width="75%" align="left" valign="top"><select name="position" id="position">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
      <option value="Director Information Technology">Director Information Technology</option>
      <option value="Director Public Relations">Director Public Relations</option>
      <option value="Logistics Coordinator">Logistics Coordinator</option>
      <option value="Staff Coordinator">Staff Coordinator</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="justify" valign="top"><span id="sprytextarea1">
      <label for="experience">What relevant experiences do you have to the position or conference?*</label>
      <span class="textareaRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><textarea name="experience" id="experience" cols="90" rows="10"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="justify" valign="top"><span id="sprytextarea2">
      <label for="skills">What skills or qualities do you have that would be an asset to the conference?*</label>
      <span class="textareaRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><textarea name="skills" id="skills" cols="90" rows="10"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="justify" valign="top"><span id="sprytextarea3">
      <label for="vision">What vision or ideas do you have for the conference or WTR?*</label>
      <span class="textareaRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><textarea name="vision" id="vision" cols="90" rows="10"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table></p>


<p><div align="left"><strong>Required Documents</strong></div>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" align="right" valign="top"><label for="resume">Resume:*</label></td>
    <td width="75%" align="left" valign="top"><input type="file" name="resume" id="resume"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top"><label for="letter">Cover Letter:*</label></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="file" name="letter" id="letter"></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<p><div align="left"><strong>Additional Information</strong></div>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" align="justify" valign="top"><label for="information">Do you have any additional information that may help us understand your your fit better?</label></td>
    <td width="75%" align="left" valign="top"><textarea name="information" cols="90" rows="10" id="information"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%" align="right"><input name="clear" type="reset" value="Clear Application"></td>
    <td width="50%" align="left"><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" onClick="MM_validateForm('fullname','','R','address','','R','city','','R','postal','','R','email','','RisEmail','phone','','R','experience','','R','skills','','R','vision','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" value="Submit Application"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</p>

</form></p>
</html>
```

PHP

```
    <?php

/* Subject and Email Variables */

    $Position = $_POST['position'];
    $emailSubject = "Application for $Position";
    $emailreply = 'WTR Technology Application Confirmation';
    $webMaster = 'shadi@wtr-tech.com';
    $applicant = $_POST['email'];

/* Gathering Data Variables */

    $Name = $_POST['fullname'];
    $Address = $_POST['address'];
    $City = $_POST['city'];
    $Province = $_POST['province'];
    $Postal = $_POST['postal'];

    $Email = $_POST['email'];
    $PhoneNumber = $_POST['phone'];
    $PhoneType = $_POST['phonetype'];

    $Experience = $_POST['experience'];
    $Skills = $_POST['skills'];
    $Vision = $_POST['vision'];

    $Resume = $_FILES['resume'];
    $CoverLetter = $_FILES['letter'];
    $Information = $_POST['information'];

/* Email sent to WTR Technology */

    $body = <<<EOD
PERSONAL DETAILS
<br><hr><hr><br>
Full Name: $Name <br>
<br>
Street Address: $Address <br>
City: $City <br>
Province: $Province <br>
Postal Code: $Postal <br>
<br>
Email address: $Email <br>
Phone Number ($PhoneType): $PhoneNumber <br>
<br>
<br>
RELEVANT EXPERIENCE
<br><hr><hr><br>
Position of Interest: $Position <br>
<br>
What relevant experiences do you have to the position or conference? <br><hr><br>
$Experience <br>
<br>
What skills or qualities do you have that would be an asset to the conference? <br><hr><br>
$Skills <br>
<br>
What vision or ideas do you have for the conference or WTR Technology? <br><hr><br>
$Vision <br>
<br>
<br>
REQUIRED DOCUMENTS
<br><hr><hr><br>
Resume: $Resume <br>
Cover Letter: $CoverLetter <br>
<br>
<br>
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION
<br><hr><hr><br>
Do you have any additional information that may help us understand your your fit better'?' <br><hr><br>
$Information <br>
EOD;

    $bodyreply = <<<EOD
<br>
Dear $Name,<br>
<br>
Your employment application at The WTR Technology has been successfully submitted.  Applications are delivered to our recruiting staff daily and are reviewed as soon as possible. Please note that changes cannot be made to your application after submittal. Should you need to modify any data or add additional documents to your application, please work with your recruiting coordinator once they have contacted you.  Thank you for your interest in an employment at WTR Technology. <br>
<br>
Best Regards <br>
<br>
<br>
<br><hr><br>
WTR Technology <br>
<br>
This e-mail message may contain confidential and/or privileged information.
If you are not an addressee or otherwise authorized to receive this message,
you should not use, copy, disclose or take any action based on this e-mail or
any information contained in the message. If you have received this material
in error, please advise the sender immediately by reply e-mail and delete this
message. Thank you.
EOD;

    $headers = "From: $webMaster\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Do you check the return from mail()?

Comment: Yes, and I receive the email exactly the way it is formatted in the body section, but the entries such as ($Name, $Address.. etc), they are not included in the email and the fields are left blank...

Comment: Is there no <head> or <body> tags in your HTML for simplicity in the question, or are these actually left out of your html document? If they are left out, perhaps the browser is not processing things quite correctly?

Comment: I didn't past them in for simplicity... I only posted the "form" portion of the code!

Comment: Hmmm in the PHP code, right at the top, add `print_r($_POST); die;` and post the output. This will help us see if your POSTED data is actually making it to PHP. If that fails, try the same with `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your form method is set to "get".

```
<form action="application.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="JobApp" lang="en">
```

Change to post as per above.

Comment: changed it... Still have the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

your `form method` is set to **get** and you are using **post** . change your form method to **post**.

```
<form action="application.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="JobApp" lang="en">
```

Comment: changed it... Still have the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your form action is **get** your script is looking for **post** they need to match

Comment: changed it... Still have the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try This Whole Code....

```html
<?php 
if($_POST)
{
 /* Subject and Email Variables */

    $Position = $_POST['position'];
    $emailSubject = "Application for $Position";
    $emailreply = 'WTR Technology Application Confirmation';
    $webMaster = 'shadi@wtr-tech.com';
    $applicant = $_POST['email'];

/* Gathering Data Variables */

    $Name = $_POST['fullname'];
    $Address = $_POST['address'];
    $City = $_POST['city'];
    $Province = $_POST['province'];
    $Postal = $_POST['postal'];

    $Email = $_POST['email'];
    $PhoneNumber = $_POST['phone'];
    $PhoneType = $_POST['phonetype'];

    $Experience = $_POST['experience'];
    $Skills = $_POST['skills'];
    $Vision = $_POST['vision'];

    $Resume = $_FILES['resume'];
    $CoverLetter = $_FILES['letter'];
    $Information = $_POST['information'];

/* Email sent to WTR Technology */

    $body = "PERSONAL DETAILS
   <br><hr><hr><br>
   Full Name: $Name <br>
   <br>
   Street Address: $Address <br>
   City: $City <br>
   Province: $Province <br>
   Postal Code: $Postal <br>
   <br>
   Email address: $Email <br>
   Phone Number ($PhoneType): $PhoneNumber <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   RELEVANT EXPERIENCE
   <br><hr><hr><br>
   Position of Interest: $Position <br>
   <br>
   What relevant experiences do you have to the position or conference? <br><hr><br>
   $Experience <br>
   <br>
   What skills or qualities do you have that would be an asset to the conference? <br><hr><br>
   $Skills <br>
   <br>
   What vision or ideas do you have for the conference or WTR Technology? <br><hr><br>
   $Vision <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   REQUIRED DOCUMENTS
   <br><hr><hr><br>
   Resume: $Resume <br>
   Cover Letter: $CoverLetter <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   ADDITIONAL INFORMATION
   <br><hr><hr><br>
   Do you have any additional information that may help us understand your your fit better'?' <br><hr><br>
   $Information <br>
   ";

    $bodyreply = "
    <br>
    Dear $Name,<br>
    <br>
    Your employment application at The WTR Technology has been successfully submitted.  Applications are delivered to our recruiting staff daily and are reviewed as soon as possible. Please note that changes cannot be made to your application after submittal. Should you need to modify any data or add additional documents to your application, please work with your recruiting coordinator once they have contacted you.  Thank you for your interest in an employment at WTR Technology. <br>
    <br>
    Best Regards <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br><hr><br>
    WTR Technology <br>
    <br>
    This e-mail message may contain confidential and/or privileged information.
    If you are not an addressee or otherwise authorized to receive this message,
    you should not use, copy, disclose or take any action based on this e-mail or
    any information contained in the message. If you have received this material
    in error, please advise the sender immediately by reply e-mail and delete this
    message. Thank you.
    ";

    $headers = "From: $webMaster\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
 //echo $body;
    $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
}
?>
<html>
<p align="left"><form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="JobApp" lang="en">
<div align="left"><strong>Personal Details</strong></div>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" align="right" valign="top"><span id="sprytextfield1">
      <label for="fullname">Full Name:*</label>
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
    <td width="35%" align="left" valign="top"><input name="fullname" type="text" id="fullname" size="35" maxlength="100"></td>
    <td width="40%" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top"><span id="sprytextfield2">
      <label for="address">Street Address:*</label>
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="address" type="text" id="address" size="35"></td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top"><span id="sprytextfield3">
      <label for="city">City:*</label>
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="city" type="text" id="city" size="30"></td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top"><span id="spryselect1">
      <label for="province">Province:*</label>
      <span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select an item.</span></span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><select name="province" id="province">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
      <option value="Alberta">Alberta</option>
      <option value="British Columbia">British Columbia</option>
      <option value="Manitoba">Manitoba</option>
      <option value="New Burnswick">New Burnswick</option>
      <option value="Newfoundland and Labrador">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
      <option value="Nova Scotia">Nova Scotia</option>
      <option value="Ontario">Ontario</option>
      <option value="Others">Others</option>
      <option value="Prince Edward Island">Prince Edward Island</option>
      <option value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
      <option value="Saskatchewan">Saskatchewan</option>
    </select></td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top"><span id="sprytextfield4">
      <label for="postal">Postal Code:*</label>
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="postal" type="text" id="postal" size="15" maxlength="7"></td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top"><span id="sprytextfield5">
      <label for="email">Email Address:*</label>
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="35"></td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top"><span id="sprytextfield6">
      <label for="phone">Phone Number:*</label>
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="25"></td>
    <td align="left"><span id="spryradio1">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="phonetype" value="Cell Phone" id="phonetype_0">
        Cell Phone</label>
      <br>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="phonetype" value="Home Phone" id="phonetype_1">
        Home Phone</label>
      <br>
      <span class="radioRequiredMsg">Please make a selection.</span></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<p><div align="left"><strong> Relevant Experience</strong></div>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" align="right" valign="top"><span id="spryselect2">
      <label for="position">Position of Interest:*</label>
      <span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select an item.</span></span></td>
    <td width="75%" align="left" valign="top"><select name="position" id="position">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
      <option value="Director Information Technology">Director Information Technology</option>
      <option value="Director Public Relations">Director Public Relations</option>
      <option value="Logistics Coordinator">Logistics Coordinator</option>
      <option value="Staff Coordinator">Staff Coordinator</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="justify" valign="top"><span id="sprytextarea1">
      <label for="experience">What relevant experiences do you have to the position or conference?*</label>
      <span class="textareaRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><textarea name="experience" id="experience" cols="90" rows="10"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="justify" valign="top"><span id="sprytextarea2">
      <label for="skills">What skills or qualities do you have that would be an asset to the conference?*</label>
      <span class="textareaRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><textarea name="skills" id="skills" cols="90" rows="10"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="justify" valign="top"><span id="sprytextarea3">
      <label for="vision">What vision or ideas do you have for the conference or WTR?*</label>
      <span class="textareaRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><textarea name="vision" id="vision" cols="90" rows="10"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table></p>


<p><div align="left"><strong>Required Documents</strong></div>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" align="right" valign="top"><label for="resume">Resume:*</label></td>
    <td width="75%" align="left" valign="top"><input type="file" name="resume" id="resume"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top"><label for="letter">Cover Letter:*</label></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="file" name="letter" id="letter"></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<p><div align="left"><strong>Additional Information</strong></div>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" align="justify" valign="top"><label for="information">Do you have any additional information that may help us understand your your fit better?</label></td>
    <td width="75%" align="left" valign="top"><textarea name="information" cols="90" rows="10" id="information"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%" align="right"><input name="clear" type="reset" value="Clear Application"></td>
    <td width="50%" align="left"><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" onClick="MM_validateForm('fullname','','R','address','','R','city','','R','postal','','R','email','','RisEmail','phone','','R','experience','','R','skills','','R','vision','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" value="Submit Application"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</p>

</form></p>
</html>
```

in this above code i have tried and it will give you proper mail in your inbox, you have to done code only now for Required documents for attachment document. i think you can do that from your own way, if you not able to do than post that i will give you solution for that...

in mail right now you will get for Resume: Array and cover Letter: Array, for that you have to write your stored file location path....
Thats it!!!!.. Try this

create php file and copy and paste whole above code in that file and run and than check your email whatever you have used on this line : $webMaster = 'shadi@wtr-tech.com'; // abc@yyy.com or whatever you want

Comment: what you have writen in $webMaster in this variable...? on this variable you have to write your email address in which you want to receive mail..